# Traffic from Chrome always shows as referral in Analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

Lately one of our ASP.NET web sites which uses some old tracking code, Namely UrchinTracker() has started showing all clicks to the site from Chrome as referrals and not direct traffic. I have done some small amount of research and couldn't find an example exactly like ours and changing the site is not an option so correcting the bug would be enough. It's not happening when customers visit from any other browser.

Comment: Unsure what this has to do with c# or asp.net...

Comment: You're unsure what the tracking code in an asp.net website written in c# has to do with asp.net or c#?  Fair enough the link is not directly obvious but for all I know it might be an inherent bug in asp.net 4 using iis7.5 so listing the technology it's developed in usually helps and since it's developed in asp.net/c# I ended up here which perhaps was my mistake.